# Микрозависания на Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Снес систему на ноутбуке, так как она перестала работать, поставил проверенную 10-ку(в последующих попытках пытался другие сборки в том числе 32-битную), появляются микрозависания, но если загрузиться в безопасном режиме то таких проблем нет, в какой службе может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, разобрался в произошедшем, проблема заключалась в сбое видеокарте, а именно после установки драйвера (полноценного использования видеокарты а не просто подачи энергии) компьютер начал производить микрозависания, переустановил систему, не стал инициализировать видеокарту и всё работает как надо